# Я на викторинные вопросы наилегчайше/наилегчайши ответил

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Я на викторинные вопросы наилегчайше ответил.

> Я на викторинные вопросы наилегчайши ответил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете простую превосходную степень слова *наилегко*.

К наречиям в простой превосходной степени прибавляется суффикс -АЙШЕ- или -ЕЙШЕ-. Суффикса -ЕЙШИ- не существует, поэтому [верно](https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/stepeni-sravneniya-narechiy) с Е:

*Я на викторинные вопросы наилегчайш**е** ответил*.

Comment: Формы "наилегчайше" нет в словаре.  В Нацкорпусе тоже.

Comment: @Sharon Позже дополню ответ. Извините, но пока нет времени на это. Спасибо за замечание.

Comment: @Sharon А разве его не существует? Слово _легчайше_ вроде есть. А приставки можно, по сути, к любому слову добавлять. Или есть приставки, не добавляемые к наречиям?

Comment: Наречие обычно образуется от прилагательного с помощью суффикса О. Я  могу предположить, что наречие образуется не от всех форм с приставкой НАИ- Или вы думаете, что ото всех? У вас есть информация на эту тему?  http://nskhuman.ru/unislov/slovar.php?nslovo=49400&lstpref=1#:~:text=Наи%20-%20формообразовательная%20единица%2C%20образующая,т.п.%2C%20а%20также%20наипоследний%2C%20наисегодняшний)

Comment: У Зализняка мало таких слов.  Вот наивысший https://dicipedia.com/dic-ru-ru-para-term-35765.htm  Там вообще странные формы указаны, но это машинный подбор форм.

Comment: У вас указана неверная схема образования наречия. Если вы считаете, что верная, то докажите это.

Comment: 1. А разве не ото всех? Если нет, то от каких не образуется? _Наилегчайший_ входит в множество образующихся от прил. наречий? 2. А почему неверная? Что именно в ней неверного? Как строятся вообще эти схемы?

Comment: Это я у вас хотела узнать. По слуху кажется, что не ото всех.  Нужна же полезная информация в ответе. Где проверить грамматические формы? Может, словарь какой есть?